# VIM Auto Wrapping

Tags: vim, vi

I cannot seem to get autowrap to work.
I've tried ":set fo ?" and the result is " formatoptions=tcq "
I just spent 30 hours in google and other sites, and 2 hours here trying to figure this out.
I've tried everything stated at: https://coderwall.com/p/wbyv_a/vim-automatic-wrapping-at-80-characters

My "lvimrc file (which I know is being sourced, because of the right blue column):

```
"" default overrides for this folder only
set ts=2
set tabstop=2
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2

set formatoptions+=t
set textwidth=79
set wrapmargin=2

set colorcolumn=80
hi ColorColumn ctermbg=blue guibg=red

highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%80v.\+/
```

And when I am in a line at col 70, and start typing, I can type right paste my blue line into the red, and no AUTO-WRAPPING happens, Any ideas?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: "lvimrc", really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AHA!!! It was:

```
:set paste
```

I went through my /home/{USER}/.vimrc  line by line, until I figured it out.

Fixed with:

```
:set nopaste
```

Comment: `:help 'paste'` has lots of nasty side-effects so it is and should never enabled by default. Removing that line altogether should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

You need two things for general automatic as-you-type linebreaks:

- `t` in the value of `:help 'formatoptions'`,
- a non-zero value for `:help 'textwidth'`.

You may also need `c` in the value of `formatoptions` if you want automatic linebreaks in comments.

Since the default value of `formatoptions` is `tcq`, all you really need is to set `textwidth` to the desired value:

```
set textwidth=80
```

[image: text]

For some (most?) programming languages, the default `formatoptions` is overridden by the active ftplugin so that only comments get that treatment. This is incidentally the case for PHP, where lines of code don't get broken but comments do:

[image: php]

Comment: I thought that's what it was, a missing text width, then I realized it is on a different machine.  On this machine, it just doesn't seem to work.  I don't know what I'm missing, but it's driving me bonkers.

Comment: yeah, I don't know what is causing this :-( I am so upset that I can't get this to work

Comment: Okay, I found out it works, IF I remove .vimrc, so something in this is causing auto-wrapping not to work.  https://github.com/PyTis/PyTis/blob/development/src/bootstrap-box/home-jlee/.vimrc  see if you can figure out what is causing it please.